# Plugin Installation

Tags: javascript, plugins, windows-installer, firebreath

I wrote a plugin in Firebreath, and I have a msi written.

I want to write a JavaScript function that will trigger an installation(a pop up in the top of the page) 
or will redirect the user to a download page.
Can someone provide an example or a helpfull link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FireBreath has an example javascript file that can be used to help with plugin detection:

https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/Installer/js/fb_installer.js

basically you use `FireBreath.isPluginInstalled("yourPlugin")` to see if the plugin has been installed yet or not.

You can use `FireBreath.injectPlugin("yourPlugin", divContainer, "pluginId", callback)` to add the plugin to the page after you have verified that the plugin is installed, and if you find that the plugin is not installed and display a download link to the MSI you can use `FireBreath.waitForInstall("yourPlugin", callback)` to have your callback function called when the plugin shows up.

The script may not be perfect, but it should give you a good starting point.

Comment: I don't want firebreath specipic functions

Comment: that's fine... just rewrite it so that they aren't firebreath specific.  You ask for javascript functions that will do that. I gave you javascript functions that will do that. It's licensed under the new BSD license, so you can pretty much do whatever you want with them.